# UTF-8 , Classic ASP and SQL Server

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, encoding, utf-8

I'm having a weird problem that is getting me really really confused here.

I'm working on internationalization of a web app, and implementing UTF-8 all over.

The app has a lot of legacy code in Classic ASP, which is working fine so far.

What is getting me confused here is the following.

From the admin side of the APP I'm saving this string to test special characters:

```
Á, É, Í, Ó, Ú, Ü, Ñ ± ' Z Ž
```

If I run the SQL Server Profiler, I do not see the `Ž` character being inserted

[image: SQL Profiler]

If I do a `Response.Write` of the query that is running the `UPDATE`, the character is there

[image: Response]

If I try to edit what was saved from the web front end, the character is there.

[image]

[image]

If I check the HTML Source code of the page I'm editing the character is correctly encoded as HTML using `Server.HTMLEncode`

[image]

If I run a select query from SQL Server Management Studio I do not see the character

[image]

I have the html meta tag to set UTF-8

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

The files are saved with UTF-8 Encoding

How can it be that the character is not visible in SQL Server Profiler or queries but if I do it from the front end the character is there?

I'm using the `N` prefix to save unicode in SQL Server and the column is of type `nvarchar(128)`

Then from another part of the system with the same setup if I try to do the same thing, the character is visible when doing the insert.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why isn't that string inside `<OPTION VALUE="here">`? How exactly are you getting it from the client-side form to the update command? Have you tried using a stored procedure and passing strongly-typed parameters instead of building strings? Have you tried moving this specific character to before the escaped apostrophes (`''`)? Are you sure the column is 128 characters and not 128 bytes (64 characters)?

Comment: Also, just as a completely pedantic thing, note that SQL Server doesn't support UTF-8.

Comment: I suppose sqlserver translates utf8 encoded characters to ucs2.

Comment: maybe your applications use windows1252, Ž is the only char missing.

Comment: @AaronBertrand The string is not in the Value because we use only the ID in the value. It is 128 characters long, I can insert strings longer than that. But the issue is that I don't see the character in the back end but it is visible from the front end.
I know it doesn't support UTF-8.

Comment: @1010 The application uses UTF-8. As mentioned in the post, the character is not visible in SQL profiler or in queries but it is visible from the client side. It's like a ghost character.

Comment: So if the long string is not in the value, let me ask again: how does it get from the text of the web page to the database?

Comment: @AaronBertrand The long string is in the value is just that character (Ž) at least only that one so far that is not visible in the DB but it is visible from the client side when editing.

Comment: @FedericoGiust I mean that maybe the msms and profiler are using a restricted character encoding.

Comment: @1010 No, as mentioned above if I insert the same character from another part of the system with the exact same setup (ASP, CodePage, etc) the character is visible via msms and profiler.

Comment: you can try select convert(varbinary, yourfield) to see what's actually stored in the db. and to see whats the difference between the strings inserted from different environments.

Comment: @1010 This is what I get `0x52006500670069007300740072006100740069006F006E00200046006500` but I have no idea how that translates to unicode characters

Comment: sqlserver uses ucs2 to encode characters using 2 bytes for each. Each pair of hex digits is a byte, but it is not the row with Ž, it says "Registration Fe"